# Newly Created Bone Moves Mesh Despite No Parenting

Tags: armature, bones

[image: My Mesh at it's current state and all of it's bones.]
First picture: My mesh and all of it's bones.

[image: I add a new bone in edit mode with Shift+A]

Second Picture: I add a new bone in edit mode with Shift+A

[image: When I go to pose mode and move the bone, the hair mesh moves with it. This is despite me having not parented the bone to anything.]

Third picture: When I go to pose mode and move the bone, the hair mesh moves with it. This is despite me having not parented the bone to anything.

I'm inexperienced with blender and am unsure of what I did to create this issue. But it's certainly an issue! Help.

Comment: More information:
I've attempted to detach the hair mesh from the armature and reattach it to the only bones it should have. It has not fixed it.

I have also attempted to detach the hair mesh and attach it to the bones in the middle, just to see if that would work. I will highlight the hair mesh, highlight the bones in the middle, but it will not attach to those. It will instead attach to the bones it was previously attached to (which were not highlighted.)

TLDR: I cannot change what bones this mesh is attached to, just if it is attached to them???

Help. What did I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentship is between the whole armature and the whole mesh, so if you create a new bone into an armature which is parent of the mesh, also the new bone will be active (an armature modifier is added to the mesh during the automatic weights parenting).

Any bone can move some vertices of the mesh if there is a vertex group which has the same exact name of the bone and some vertices have some weight assigned to it, so you can choose which vertices to move (and how much) assigning some vertex weight to the different vertex groups of the mesh.

To solve your problem you can select the mesh, go to edit mode, in the properties panel, vertex groups tab (green triangle with dots), select the vertex group which has the same name of the newly create bone, select all vertices and click "Remove" button.

Then you will select the vertices you want to be child of that bone and click "Assign".

Check some tutorials about weight painting, which let you assign weights more easily.

[image]